# High performance Ruby listbox

Tags: ruby, user-interface, listbox

I need to make a small application in Ruby that will display log lines received over TCP in different colors.
What is a recommended GUI framework to use for this type of app?

I should work on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

[Shoes](http://shoooes.net/) is a great lightweight GUI framework with mac, linux, and windows support.

Answer (score 0):

RuGUI is a framework which aims to help building desktop applications: http://rugui.org/ and https://github.com/rugui/rugui